# Trouble installing ninja for the purpose of using folium

Tags: python, cmake, pycharm, folium, ninja

I am getting an error message that indicates that pip is unable to build the wheel for the ninja package. I have tried the following troubleshooting steps, but the problem persists:

I have checked that I have CMake installed on my system.
I have checked that my CMake installation is up to date.
I have tried running the following command in a terminal to install the ninja package:
pip install ninja
I have tried installing the folium package without the ninja dependency:
pip install folium --no-deps
I tried to create a path but it is still not working, the path for Cmake works fine but for ninja it does not work I think
Can you please help me troubleshoot this issue?

```
  Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [269 lines of output]


      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)' generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

      -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)' generator - failure

      -- Trying 'Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143' generator

      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.32919.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.32919/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.32919.0
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.32919/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Configuring done (4.4s)
      -- Generating done (0.0s)
      -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/_cmake_test_compile/build

      -- Trying 'Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143' generator - success

      Configuring Project
        Working directory:
          C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build
        Command:
          'C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE' 'C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c' -G 'Visual Studio 17 2022' --no-warn-un
used-cli '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-install' -DPYTHON_V
ERSION_STRING:STRING=3.10.5 -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE '-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-htuu7292\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\reso
urces\cmake' '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=C:\Users\23052\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\bin\python.exe' '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\23052\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv/
include/python3.10' '-DPython_EXECUTABLE:PATH=C:\Users\23052\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\bin\python.exe' '-DPython_ROOT_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\23052\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\v
env' -DPython_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER '-DPython_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\23052\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv/include/python3.10' '-DPython3_EXECUTABLE:PATH=C:\Users\23052\Pyc
harmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\bin\python.exe' '-DPython3_ROOT_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\23052\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv' -DPython3_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER '-DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\23052\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv/include/python3.10' -T v143 -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.32919.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.32919.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.32919/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.32919/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- *********************************************
      -- Ninja Python Distribution
      --
      --   BUILD_VERBOSE             : OFF
      --   RUN_NINJA_TEST            : ON
      --
      --   ARCHIVE_DOWNLOAD_DIR      : C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/_skbuild/mingw_x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
      --
      --     src_archive             : windows_source
      --     <src_archive>_url       : https://github.com/Kitware/ninja/archive/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.zip
      --     <src_archive>_sha256    : d605f36bce5cf50799ad3a56e7d388d7c0cf6731db40f46334e076c7e036bfaa
      -- *********************************************
      CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3136 (message):
        The DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option was not given and policy CMP0135 is
        not set.  The policy's OLD behavior will be used.  When using a URL
        download, the timestamps of extracted files should preferably be that of
        the time of extraction, otherwise code that depends on the extracted
        contents might not be rebuilt if the URL changes.  The OLD behavior
        preserves the timestamps from the archive instead, but this is usually not
        what you want.  Update your project to the NEW behavior or specify the
        DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option with a value of true to avoid this
        robustness issue.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:4345 (_ep_add_download_command)
        CMakeLists.txt:65 (ExternalProject_add)
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      -- download_ninja_source - URL: https://github.com/Kitware/ninja/archive/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.zip
      -- SuperBuild - CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
      -- Configuring done (3.4s)
      -- Generating done (0.0s)
      -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/_skbuild/mingw_x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
      MSBuild version 17.8.0-preview-23376-06+f413f5497 for .NET Framework

      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory
 cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
        1>Checking Build System
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory
 cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\download_ninja_source.vcxproj]
        Creating directories for 'download_ninja_source'
        Building Custom Rule C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/CMakeLists.txt
        Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'download_ninja_source'
        -- Downloading...
           dst='C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/_skbuild/mingw_x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.zip'
           timeout='none'
           inactivity timeout='none'
        -- Using src='https://github.com/Kitware/ninja/archive/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.zip'
        -- verifying file...
               file='C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/_skbuild/mingw_x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.zip'
        -- Downloading... done
        -- extracting...
             src='C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/_skbuild/mingw_x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.zip'
             dst='C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/Ninja-src'
        -- extracting... [tar xfz]
        -- extracting... [analysis]
        -- extracting... [rename]
        -- extracting... [clean up]
        -- extracting... done
        No update step for 'download_ninja_source'
        No patch step for 'download_ninja_source'
        No configure step for 'download_ninja_source'
        No build step for 'download_ninja_source'
        No install step for 'download_ninja_source'
        Completed 'download_ninja_source'
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory
 cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\build_ninja.vcxproj]
        Creating directories for 'build_ninja'
        Building Custom Rule C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/CMakeLists.txt
        No download step for 'build_ninja'
        No update step for 'build_ninja'
        No patch step for 'build_ninja'
        Performing configure step for 'build_ninja'
        loading initial cache file C:/Users/23052/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-wswntfyb/ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c/_skbuild/mingw_x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/build_ninja-prefix/tmp/build_ninja-cache-Release.cmake
        -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.32919.0
        -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.32919.0
        -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
        -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
        -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.32919/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
        -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft 

              Creating directory "cmTC_6e519.dir\Debug\cmTC_6e519.tlog\".
            InitializeBuildStatus:
              Creating "cmTC_6e519.dir\Debug\cmTC_6e519.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
              Touching "cmTC_6e519.dir\Debug\cmTC_6e519.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
            ClCompile:
              C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.32919\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _
WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_6e519.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_6e519.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W1 /Gd
 /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\Ninja-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-uxg2e9\testCCompiler.c"
              Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.32919 for x64
              testCCompiler.c
              Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
              cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inl
-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\build_ninja.vcxproj]     
            Done Building Project "C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\Ninja-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-uxg2e9\cmTC_6e519.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

            Build FAILED.

            "C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\Ninja-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-uxg2e9\cmTC_6e519.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
            (PrepareForBuild target) ->
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory
 cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a071
96d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\Ninja-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-uxg2e9\cmTC_6e519.vcxproj] [C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\build_ninja.vcxproj]
    

                1 Warning(s)
                1 Error(s)

            Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29


          CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
        Call Stack (most recent call first):
          CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)


      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(249,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\
Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build\CMakeFiles\b8b44d83d4bf3c40f8c234359fbb1c25\build_ninja-

      An error occurred while building with CMake.
        Command:
          'C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE' --build . --target install --config Release --
        Install target:
          install
        Source directory:
          C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c
        Working directory:
          C:\Users\23052\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wswntfyb\ninja_43d1b68c9a4a45d3b87c02a07196d78c\_skbuild\mingw_x86_64-3.10\cmake-build
      Please check the install target is valid and see CMake's output for more information.

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
Failed to build ninja
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: "I am getting an error message that indicates that..." - Do not **describe** the error your got. Instead, paste into the question post the **exact error message**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Alright